# Aiohttp+Asyncio Seems To Be Inconsistent in Tripadvisor Travel Site

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I was trying to asynchronously request page data from tripadvisor travel site using aiohttp+asyncio, but it seems that in multiple occasions, the get() method is stuck for almost a minute and then results in TimeoutError.

I created a similar script using the requests library and confirmed that there are times that the code with requests library works while the code with aiohttp+asyncio does not.

Here are the codes:

##### Using aiohttp + asyncio

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import asyncio

home_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com'
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36'
    }


async def main():
    async with ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        tourist_sites_url = home_url + '/Attractions-g294245-Activities-a_allAttractions.true-Philippines.html'
        async with session.get(tourist_sites_url) as response:
            print(f'{response.status=}\n')
            print(await response.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

##### Using requests

```
from requests import Session

home_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com'
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36'
    }


def main():
    with Session() as session:
        tourist_sites_url = home_url + '/Attractions-g294245-Activities-a_allAttractions.true-Philippines.html'
        response = session.get(tourist_sites_url, headers=headers)
        print(f'{response.status_code=}\n')
        print(response.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**What shall I do in order for the code with aiohttp+asyncio to work on tripadvisor website?**

Thank you very much!

Comment: seems like a TripAdvisor issue more than code, maybe they are blocking you after a certain number of requests

Comment: Hi @gold_cy. Would it be possible to block the code with aiohttp+asyncio and permit the code with python-requests library? They are both using the same PC